# in c++, what is the difference between two function calls that use pointers?

Tags: c++, matrix

In the first function call, I'm sending in a matrix pass by reference. Isn't the second way the same? I thought matrices were default pass by reference.

Here's the first case:

```
phi= new double[15]; //phi is a dynamically allocated array

function(double *phi) //calls phi with what SHOULD be default pass by reference
```

Second case:

```
function(double *&phi) //calls phi with pass by reference?
```

There should be no difference between the two, right?

The reason I ask is because my code segment faults when I neglect the '&' sign and try to assign a value to phi outside of the function that I dynamically allocated it in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, your function declaration accepts a pointer by value.

In the second case, your function declaration accepts a pointer by reference. You could change the pointer in the function.

Comment: Oh~! That makes perfect sense! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding what "passing as reference" means. When you pass a variable as a reference, you give the function the ability to change the value of the variable.

Say I have a function defined as:

```
doIt(int i)
```

and I call it like this:

```
main()
{
    int a = 2;

    doIt(a);
}
```

The function can't change the value of the "a" variable.

In your case, you are using a *pointer*. If I had the following function:

```
doItWithAPointer(int* a)
```

and called it like this:

```
main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int* pa = &a;

    doItWithAPointer(pa);
}
```

I could now change the value of "a". Why? because I can access its value through the pointer. What I can't do is *change the value of the actual parameter*, in this case "pa" or, in other words, make it point to another address.

Now, finally if I declare my function like this:

```
doItWithAPointerReference(int* &a)
```

and called it like this:

```
main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int* pa = &a;

    doItWithAPointerReference(pa);
}
```

I can still change the value of the "a" variable through the pointer, but I can also directly change the value of "pa" since I have a reference to it!

Comment: "**The function can't change the value of the "a" variable.**" Yes, if it's passing by reference it can change it, and the change will affect the original. If you're passing by const reference, then it can't, or if it's passing by value, then it's only locally changed.

Comment: Doh! It should have read "doIt(int i)" (without the reference). Corrected.

Comment: Ah, you edited your original post, and the mistake was a typo! Changed the -1 to a +1. Thought you were posting a huge mistake. Good ol' programming, where one symbol makes all the difference in the world!